# 500 error when publishing my Nextjs app on Netlify, when i use "use client"

Tags: next.js, netlify

What could be the possible cause of the "Internal Server Error" with status code 500 when publishing my app on Netlify, based on the error message and log provided?

I have found that when I remove components that "use client" from my main page, it starts working again. What could I be doing wrong?

I need to use "useClient" for managing state with useState.

Additionally, I noticed that when I type "/about" in the URL and then navigate back to the main page using a link, it starts working again. However, the issue reoccurs when I reload the page.

P.S. The console is prompting me to visit this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred

[image: 500]

my current default page code:

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Description from "../components/description";
import FilterCardsClient from "../components/filters/filterCards";
import ErrorBoundary from "../components/errorBoundary";

export default function Page(props) {
  return (
    <div className="my-8 w-full rounded-lg p-4 text-gray-600 md:p-0">
      {/* Description */}
      <Description />

      {/* Cards */}
      <ErrorBoundary fallback={<p>Something went wrong</p>}>
        <FilterCardsClient props={props} />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My ErrorBoundary component is not providing any assistance.

```
import React from "react";

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Example "componentStack":
    //   in ComponentThatThrows (created by App)
    //   in ErrorBoundary (created by App)
    //   in div (created by App)
    //   in App
    logErrorToMyService(error, info.componentStack);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return this.props.fallback;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Netlify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use any error boundary. In nextjs 13.4 you can directly create a `error.tsx/error.jsx` file in your folder for example:
If you're using Nextjs 13 App Router and you create a folder name `about` then create some files `page.tsx`, `error.tsx`

`Default Page`

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Description from "../components/description";
import FilterCardsClient from "../components/filters/filterCards";

export default function Page(props) {
  return (
    <div className="my-8 w-full rounded-lg p-4 text-gray-600 md:p-0">
      {/* Description */}
      <Description />
        <FilterCardsClient props={props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to show some loading UI then you have to create `loading.tsx` file

**Remember .tsx extension is used only if you're working with `typescript`  otherwise use `.jsx` and `.js` file extension**

You can checkout the documentation of Nextjs 13.4 App Router and i suggest you to don't use `Class Componenets`

Reference: [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions)

Comment: I found a solution by removing the src/app directory in Next.js and working solely with the pages directory.